# Selecting duplicate rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am populating a dataframe based on values of a column. The rows in the dataframe may be repeated.

```
df = DataFrame({'A' : [5,6,3,4], 'B' : [1,2,3, 5]})
out[16]:
   A  B
0  5  1
1  6  2
2  3  3
3  4  5

df[df['A'].isin([3, 6])]


Out[17]: 
   A  B
1  6  2
2  3  3
```

This is expected. What I need is something different. I need to have duplicate rows. How is it possible?

```
df[df['A'].isin([3, 6,3])]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `get_indexer_for` to find the ordinal index corresponding to the values [3,6,3] in `df['A']`. Then use `df.iloc` to look up the rows:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [5,6,3,4], 'B' : [1,2,3, 5]})
idx = pd.Index(df['A']).get_indexer_for([3,6,3])
print(df.iloc[idx])
```

prints

```
   A  B
2  3  3
1  6  2
2  3  3
```

Comment: Sweet. This is what I was looking for.